# What is the word for an inline editor's comment?

Tags: single-word-requests, editing

What is the word for an inline editor's comment?  As an example, I was reading a particular software product's online documentation (more of a wiki) and I was surprised to find that there were certain sections that had author/editor notes where I expected documentation content.  For example, there was a feature that was described under the subheadings: Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007/2010, and Outlook 2013.  The Outlook 2003 and 2007/2010 sections had several paragraphs and diagrams of content, but the Outlook 2013 section just had a couple sentences of content, followed by the sentence:

> Please include registry edit necessary for enabling the editor dialog

What is the proper word for this sentence, that is, an editor comment or author's note to oneself in the body of the content?

Answer (score 1):

I think **annotation** works here:

> A critical or explanatory note; a commentary.

(American Heritage Dictionary)

Annotations are widely used within the software industry, and can be attached to parts of a document, images, source code commits, etc.

Comment: The reason I don't like annotation here is that annotation sounds too normal, as annotations can also refer to additional commentary on the CONTENT.  What I'm looking for is when the author or editor has added 'meta' commentary not intended for the reader.

Comment: I see, but annotations certainly cover meta comments intended for all kinds of purposes and audiences, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annotation

Comment: Not sayin you're wrong, just not the word I'm looking for.  In this case, the more specific, the better.